# integration jpa + mongodb "does not work"

Tags: mongodb, hibernate, jpa

Integration does not work mongodb + hibernate, does not throw any exception . after running the em.insert line ( p ) does not insert any record .

```
public class Principal {

  public static void main(String[] args) {

    EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence
    .createEntityManagerFactory("UnidadOGM");

    System.out.println(emf);
    EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();
    Persona p = new Pwersona();
    p.setId("1");
    p.setNombre("Alberto");
    p.setNombre("Perez");
    em.persist(p);
    List<Persona> lista=em.createQuery("select p from Persona p",Persona.class).getResultList();

    for(Persona p :lista) {

      System.out.println(p.getNombre());
      System.out.println(p.getApellidos());
    }
    em.close();

  }

}




Class Persona

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;

import org.hibernate.annotations.Type;

@Entity
public class Persona {

@Id
@Type(type = "objectid")
private String id;

public String getId() {
return id;
}

public void setId(String id) {
this.id = id;
}

private String nombre;
private String apellidos;

public String getApellidos() {
return apellidos;
}

public void setApellidos(String apellidos) {
this.apellidos = apellidos;
}

public String getNombre() {
return nombre;
}

public Persona() {
super();
}

public Persona(String nombre) {
super();
this.nombre = nombre;
}

public void setNombre(String nombre) {
this.nombre = nombre;
}

}
```

In the persistence.xml , does not detect the configuration database. If I change the port of the database or the name of the database with one that does not exist, does not jump no exception . Yes, read the persistence.xml file if persistence-unit change UnidadOGM , by another chain jumps an exception that does not exist persistence-unit .

```
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence
http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd"
version="2.0">
<persistence-unit name="UnidadOGM" transaction-type="JTA">

<provider>org.hibernate.ogm.jpa.HibernateOgmPersistence</provider>
<class>com.arquitecturajava.Persona</class>
<properties>

<property name="hibernate.ogm.datastore.provider" value="mongodb" />
<property name="hibernate.ogm.datastore.grid_dialect"
value="org.hibernate.ogm.datastore.mongodb.MongoDBDialect" />
<property name="hibernate.ogm.datastore.database" value="arquitecturajava" />
<property name="hibernate.ogm.mongodb.host" value="127.0.0.1" />
<property name="hibernate.ogm.mongodb.port" value="27017" />
</properties>
</persistence-unit>

</persistence>
```

dependencies:

```
<dependency>
<groupId>org.hibernate.ogm</groupId>
<artifactId>hibernate-ogm-mongodb</artifactId>
<version>4.1.0.Beta8</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
<groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
<artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.0-api</artifactId>
<version>1.0.1.Final</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
<groupId>org.jboss.spec.javax.transaction</groupId>
<artifactId>jboss-transaction-api_1.1_spec</artifactId>
<version>1.0.0.Final</version>
<scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
<groupId>org.jboss.jbossts</groupId>
<artifactId>jbossjta</artifactId>
<version>4.16.4.Final</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need a transaction to insert data

```
EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence
    .createEntityManagerFactory("UnidadOGM");

    EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();
    Persona p = new Pwersona();
    p.setId("1");
    p.setNombre("Alberto");
    p.setNombre("Perez");

    em.getTransaction().begin();

    em.persist(p);

    em.getTransaction().commit();
    em.close();
```

If you want to insert and query data in one transaction, probably, you need to call `flush()` after inserting data.

Comment: thanks , this is the result :                                                                          Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: A JTA EntityManager cannot use getTransaction()
 at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.getTransaction(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1368)
 at org.hibernate.ogm.jpa.impl.OgmEntityManager.getTransaction(OgmEntityManager.java:591)
 at com.di.maven.App.main(App.java:25)

Comment: @user1358518 Please, add a full stack trace to your question.

Comment: @user1358518 If you are working with a standalone application you should set the transaction type in the persistence as RESOURCE_LOCAL